# Could we have up/down votes shown separately and permanently for each user?

Tags: support, design

Could we have up/down votes shown separately and permanently for each question and answers and for each user?

Something like that, for example:

[image]

Comment: I think that's a no. It's not shown until you click it because always showing it without clicking would cause the requests to be too expensive. Or something like that.

Comment: Websockets? RealTime StackOverFlow? Will be, but not now, in the near future. :) Tx u, @LéoLam.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [Why is it a privilege to view vote counts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69852/why-is-it-a-privilege-to-view-vote-counts) and [Show Total Votes (or Up/Down Votes)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes), the calculation of the votes is too expensive.

Quoting [Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1007/245360):

> The total vote count (score) is denormalized, but the individual up/down vote counts are not.
>
> So to display it on every post would incur 2 vote table queries * number of visible questions / answers. Our DB is fast, but the vote table is pretty massive, and not doing a query is always faster than doing it.

By capping 99% of the users (users that are not [Established Users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)) and not showing it in the first place, the overall performance is increased.

Comment: [Established User](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [this Stack App](https://stackapps.com/q/3082/9699) to get this "privilege" without 1,000 rep.

Comment: @LéoLam excelent App. Thank You. :) Wonderful.

Answer (score 1):

“View Vote totals” without 1000 rep alternatives.
*[trick and hint from @LéoLam]*

**Important note:** don't forget to click on Question or Answer score to see it.

See original post message: "View Vote totals" without 1000 rep - Stack Apps https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep

**Screenshot example:**

[image]