# Auto expand vote count / warn when the post is controversial

Tags: discussion, feature-request

There are many answers which are controversial in Stack Overflow. These answers are usually bad (but shouldn't be deleted) but OP is not aware of that.

We do want to warn visitors from using the code suggested in such questions. We can:

- Downvote the answer
- Leave a comment
- Suggest a different answer

However, many Google visitors don't usually pay attention to comments - All what they care about are the shiny green "v" supported by big number of upvotes.

This thread [Can we do something about old/outdated/terrible highly upvoted answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314157/can-we-do-something-about-old-outdated-terrible-highly-upvoted-answers) brings an important issue that we should know how to handle. I want to suggest auto-expanding the vote count or maybe adding a small disclaimer when the post is controversial<sup>*</sup> (maybe if the count > threshold and 1/3 of the votes are down). For example, a "dangerous" answer will look like:

[image: Controversial count]

Maybe with a message indicating that something doesn't feel good with this post.

Pros:

- It might prevent blindly copying-pasting answers without realizing its consequences
- It's guaranteed to be viewed (as opposed to comments)
- Will leave the answer as "how not to" for future users

Keep in mind that I'm not requesting this for *all* posts, only for specific posts that have many attention/votes and are really controversial.

Please let me know why you think it's a good/bad idea, your input is highly appreciated.

<sup>* I have many suggestions regarding the definition of "controversial" - We can thin about it together if you agree with the basic idea.</sup>

Comment: "but shouldn't be deleted" Why not? If they are verifiably wrong, they are at best noise polluting the site, at worst actively harmful.

Comment: @Magisch Not really, some answers do address the question and can have additional value (even if their quality is bad) - Someone can know "how not to". Deleting it might hide the dangerous impact of using it. See the linked discussion.

Comment: Too much collateral damage.  SO users have a very unhealthy attitude towards "No, you can't do that" answers.  Pretty important that they get posted, there is no upper limit on how much time programmers spend on trying to do something impossible.  But never appreciated, they demand to able to do it anyway.  Such answers get voted "unhelpful" with gusto, even though they are actually very helpful.

Comment: @HansPassant I think this will help people have another look at other answers before they pick the problematic one.

Comment: I like the basic idea, but I'm not sure if showing the vote breakdown gives enough information. For example, it would be hard to tell the difference between an answer that was once correct and is now badly outdated and one that was once incorrect but was later edited into shape. Maybe a [sparkline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparkline) showing how the answer is trending would fix that?

Comment: I really like the sparkline idea, @BilltheLizard, maybe it could be put in place for answers older than specific time.

Comment: @BilltheLizard That sounds good. Don't you think expanding it would give an indication about its quality? If it's not expanded some users might think that it's 100% agreed on.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I think expanding the vote count to get people's attention is a good idea. For the example you gave (+136/-71), I'd say that's *probably* a bad answer that used to be good, but newer users might not be able to tell.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Why won't they given that >50% of the votes are negative? We can also consider an auto-generated message warning about a possible deprecation.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Only 1/3 of the votes are negative. You still can't really tell by the vote ratio because you don't know *when* the votes were cast. If all of the upvotes came first, then the downvotes, I know that the answer is probably outdated. If all of the downvotes came first, then the upvotes, I know that it was probably a bad answer that got fixed later.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Good points. We can of course consider them and improve the request.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Either way, it tells you that something up.  From there it puts you on your guard, encouraging one to, for example, read the comments, and the comments would almost certainly explain why the answer is controversial.  So the reader just needs to be given a reason to care to read the comments.

Comment: @Servy Yes, the comments might tell you why the post is controversial, but they won't tell you which way the wind is blowing as quickly as a trend line.

Comment: @BilltheLizard If the up/down votes aren't shown on posts because it's too computationally expensive to generate it for posts when loading the page, I wouldn't hold out much hope of having a graph of all votes over time shown to all users at all times.

Comment: @Servy I'm not suggesting that.

Comment: How would this work given that the ability to see votes is a privilege you get at 1K rep? Do we get rid of the rep requirement?

Comment: @bsmp what's the problem to make exceptions? In this very specific case?

Comment: *what's the problem to make exceptions?* Someone who actually works on the site's code would have to answer that. I have no idea whether making an exception for a privilege is harder than just getting rid of the privilege.

Comment: @bsmp anyway, I find this privilege silly.. Vote count is important and can give hints about answer's quality.

Comment: @BilltheLizard The whole graph of votes might be just too much. What about up/down-pointing arrows like in the weather forecast showing the trend. They are quite intuitive and give valuable extra information about recent voting behavior. It would probably also okay to just calculate the trend once per day/week if it's too expensive otherwise.

Comment: Showing vote counts is a [performance issue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275777/could-we-have-up-down-votes-shown-separately-and-permanently-for-each-user/275778#275778). They probably would have just let it visible if it wasn't for that.

Comment: @Trilarion - With a percentage change? *This post's score has gone up 15% in the last week.*

Comment: @Trilarion Yes, if a trendline for controversial posts is too expensive, then a static image showing an upward or downward trend should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Simply showing the score clearly misses information about the controversiality of the voting. Currently seeing the plus/minus votes is a privilege gained by enough reputation.

Instead of Auto/Expanding the vote count which is not intuitive enough, I would rather like to add some kind of **tag, symbol or notification** to the answer (visible to everyone) in case it is controversial. If everyone can see this they might think twice before mindless upvoting of bad answers.

**How to define controversality?**

As in the question. For clarity:

Average Vote = Score / Total Number of Votes

which is a number between [-1,1]. If this number is in [-0.5, 0.7] (or some other suitable interval around 0) and the total number of votes (to avoid noise influence) is larger than say 10, then the answer is controversial.

**How to show this?**

- As a tag: "controversial" (with a suitable tooltip)
- As a symbol: Displayed either at the bottom or next to the score
- As a message: Below the answer: "Voting on this answer is controversial. What it could mean."

Comment: This might later be extended with other qualifications like "regarded deprecated", "tutorial like answer", ... in case there is demand.

Answer (score 1):

Users that *can* see vote counts aren't the ones that need protecting. They have [enough rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) to know how the site works.

Users that would need this kind of protection need it *because* they don't pay enough attention to other answers. They don't read comments. They just grab the accepted answer and use it.

Adding something to the UI doesn't help them. They won't notice.

Comment: Expanding them for *all* users. Why won't this help? Isn't the fact that 1/3 of the votes are negative enough to think again?

Comment: Maroun, the users that blindly copy the accepted answer don't care about / pay attention to vote count. Expanding it doesn't make a significant difference. Otherwise, they'd have used the answer that has twice the upvotes, but wasn't accepted, back in the day.

Comment: They copied it because of the amount of upvotes. (Many of my colleagues decide that it's a good answer only because it has >50 upvotes). What I'm saying is that once they have BOTH negative and positive counts already expanded, it might give them an indication that something is bad.

Comment: If they copy an answer based on the amount of upvotes, there isn't a problem, since the proper answer usually receives more upvotes than a incorrect accepted answer.