# What is the purpose of viewing vote counts?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, privileges, vote-count

I reached 1k reputation today :-) and I received the [established user privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user).

This means that I received an expanded user-card and the ability to view vote count privileges.

I am however unsure what use the of seeing the vote count is.  It's pretty fun but it does not seem to be of much use at this point.  I can see this coming in handy when [casting reopen and close votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) (a privilege that is not earned until 3k) and other even higher reputation moderation privileges but I have not got to that point yet.

Why is this awarded at this reputation and how is this supposed to be helpful for a low reputation user like me?

Comment: Related: *[Why is it a privilege to view vote counts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69852)*

Comment: I find it a lot more useful on Meta than on the main site; sometimes there's a feature request or discussion made that is a big issue for many people that the community is pretty split on, and instead of seeing (-2) for the question's score, you can see (+84,-86) or whatever and you realize that a lot of people have opinions on the topic.

Comment: @DavyM  So it's a good way of seeing how many agree and disagree.  That's very useful

Comment: The same happens for questions sometimes to a lesser extent, it might be -4/+5 for example.

Comment: @alain. Yes I can see that.  So one use it to see how many people agree/disagree with an answer.  What can I conclude from votes like that other than many people agree and disagree

Comment: Statistically, the larger the sample, the more likely it is to be representative (with various caveats). So `+1/0` isn't necessarily meaningful; `+47/-46` suggests a genuinely controversial / evenly-split point of debate. Whether that's "_useful_" or just "_interesting_" probably varies by person.

Comment: So this is a way of seeing options.  Does this also help with judging quality?

Comment: `Does this also help with judging quality?` in a way, yes - a +0/-5 post is usually *very* likely to be of low quality (although one should think for oneself and always judge the post independently from the vote count; swarm intelligence is not infallible!) while a +45/-55 post is controversial, probably an edge case, but recognized as good/useful by a significant chunk of the community, so definitely worth a very close look

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thank you.  I can see there are many subtle purposes to this privilege now

Comment: Related to Davy's point: [Please let every member see vote counts on Meta, regardless of reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360088)

Comment: When you earn this privilege early, you will be a real pro at the time when you start to really need the vote counts.

Comment: @Teemu XD good point

Comment: I use the userscript to see vote counts and honestly it doesn't feel right to use SE without it, even on the non-meta sites. a 2(+10/-8) answer on SO might mean ["this answer looks good in theory but fails simple edge cases"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8091865/4975230).

Comment: @jrh it really shows you what general the opinion is on the answer/question really.  I didn't realise the user script works on all SE sites.  Thank you.

Answer (score 23):

> Why is this awarded at this reputation and how is this supposed to be helpful for a low reputation user like me?

I'll answer the second part of your question.

I find it helpful because it makes a difference for me to consider taking an answer to my code if it has a total score of, let's say, 80 if it's 81 upvotes and only 1 downvote, versus having +120 upvotes and -40.

Viewing both positive and negative votes gives an indication about how much the post is controversial, and that's important because it means that although more users found it helpful, it wasn't totally correct for others (I even suggested having [a trend line](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314285/lets-spark-controversial-answers) on such posts). If I find such posts, I dig more and try to find why it wasn't considered that good for some users.

Comment: Can this also help determine the reliability of the code the  answer-er/asker  give?

Comment: I really wish this was available to everyone - in fact, I wish it was the default vote view.

Comment: you have to work to get privileges, that's the spirit. 1 rep users can post questions & answer questions, nothing more.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The majority of privileges you're working towards are about moderation. Viewing vote counts is mostly useful for deciding how helpful an answer is likely to be to you. It's a bit odd that it's gated behind 1k rep. Millions of anonymous viewers wouldn't be able to tell that a highly upvoted answer is in fact extremely controversial.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: It's a privilege not because 1-rep users don't deserve it, but because server performance doesn't support it.

Comment: @NathanTuggy You could make that into an answer if you want looking at the links I've been given.

Answer (score 6):

Since Meta and the Main Site are linked in terms of rep, being able to see up and down votes helps a lot when you are looking for a meta post to direct someone to.

For example, if you come across an answer on Meta with a score of 10, that doesn't really tell you if the community generally accepts it or not. If the score is 10/0, then I might include a link to it when telling another user to do or not to do something. If the score is 90/-80, then I might reconsider the strength of my position on the subject.

Comment: Thank you I can see there are many cases where this is useful when directing users to reference.

Answer (score 5):

It's just one data point that *could* conceivably help someone with some knowledge of how the system works make a more informed decision. The feature was initially gated at 1k for performance reasons more than trust reasons, but I don't think performance is as much of a concern as it used to be. Still, 1k seems a pretty nice place for it to unlock, so there's no compelling reason to change it.

It could:

- As [JDB noted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/362220/50049) help you see if there's more evidence of consensus surrounding something here on Meta.
- As [Maroun noted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/362219/50049) help you see if an answer might be controversial

... and while those are very good *practical* applications of the feature, we're sure there could be more in the course of users noticing that something just doesn't seem right as they use their flags to let someone know.

Some of the biggest cases of voting rings, plagiarism and other shenanigans I've ever uncovered have been through noticing an odd voting pattern on a single post, and digging into it from there.

So, while the two things this feature *kind of* help should be done in a more formal capacity by the system (meta needs a much more deliberate means of asking for and showing consensus, old answers need a better means of deprecation, etc) - the feature still surfaces that tiny bit of signal that when combined with good ole fashioned human intuition, helps surface real problems that might have gone unnoticed.

It might be worth moving that to a lower rep level, because it helps users better grok into what characteristics go into a great (or even controversial) answer, but having it at 1k has worked pretty well so far.

More succinctly, to use a toolbox analogy, it's more like a flashlight than a 12mm wrench. It has a variety of applications that we trust you'll find rather than a note saying "use this if you encounter any 12mm bolts".