# Should +15/-10 question score be an alert?

Tags: discussion, voting

There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39349894/4723795) tagged as [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm) which had bounty of 200 opened for a while. The OP has made a casting for the algorithm which would do what he wants but what he couldn't specify.

This has resulted in the following score:

[image]

In my opinion this question is 'too broad' or 'primarily opinion-based'. Is it? I've read somewhere on meta that those questions often have many different answers but I couldn't find interpretations of such voting.

What do you think? Is it a good question or too broad or primarily opinion-based? I wouldn't bother if the accepted answer hadn't been the well known algorithm so it can be now said that the question was about an algorithm that the OP hadn't known before.

Comment: I personally don't see what this question has to do with programming at all - it's a maths question independent of any kind of programming language or framework and so I'd say it was off-topic.

Comment: So we have another option - offtopic.

Comment: I'm not sure the score should be an alert, yes it shows people are divided, but it doesn't tell what people are divided about? Does this alert provide any extra feature that's going to help moderate the system? Not likely in my opinion.

Comment: It probably only has that many upvotes because it has a cute story in the question. It should be closed.

Comment: @Draken as we don't have many questions in Triage queue, there could be another filter that would add such questions automatically.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Auto expand vote count / warn when the post is controversial](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314168/auto-expand-vote-count-warn-when-the-post-is-controversial)

Comment: @Stijn I like the fact that the linked question has +17/-17 score.

Comment: I just cast the final close vote on that. I fail to see how thats on topic on SO. Its more like lots of math with a side of (incomplete) code.

Comment: There is just no point to alerting anybody when a bountied question gets a lot of attention, nobody can do anything useful.  That the voting is lively is not a surprise either, lots of likes because it isn't the usual "debug my code" or "google this for me" fare and lots of dislikes because muggles don't think you should have to read a Potter book to answer a question.  No point in doing it after the bounty period is over either, whatever damage could be done was done by then.  There will be a lot more of this as moderating content gets harder every day, can't waste time on the small stuff.

Comment: From my POV, the question said "show me the best algorithm which made fairest calculation through all students" and certainly passed the border of "off-topic question". It is OK if the algorithm at least contains piece of code including which effort had taken to solve "fair calculation", or contains request to modify existing code sample for different kind of result(s).